# wxPython - Button size being ignored on OSX

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I'm taking the first steps to move from .NET to Python but I'm already having a few headaches regarding the GUI design.

For some reason, passing the size attribute to a wx.Button seems to be kind of ignored. And I say "kind of"  because the actual space seems to change but the actual button keeps occupying the same space:

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    self.InitUI()

  def InitUI(self):

    self.SetSize((800, 600))
    self.SetTitle('Main Menu')
    self.Centre()
    self.Show(True)
    ''' Fill the form '''
    self.lblUsername = wx.StaticText(self, size=(80, -1), pos=(20,20), label="Username:" )
    self.txtUsername = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(140, -1), pos=(100,20), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
    self.lblPassword = wx.StaticText(self, size=(80, -1), pos=(20,50), label="Password:" )
    self.txtPassword = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(140, -1), pos=(100,50), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)

    self.btnOK = wx.Button( self, label="OK", pos=(260, 16), size=(50,50))
    self.btnOK.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClickOK)



    self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
    self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Ready')

  def onClickOK(self, e):
    print "Button triggered"


def main():

  ex = wx.App()
  Example(None)
  ex.MainLoop() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

No matter what size I set, the Button won't stretch (it will be centered as if all the space was actually being used, but will still be small).

Can anyone spot what am I doing wrong?

[image: wx.Button net resized correctly]

Comment: This might not be the answer you wished for - but wx is not really a good cross-platform ui toolkit. The reason is that it's a meta-toolkit (meaning it wraps others), and windows-first, the other OS are just tagged along. In this day & age with Qt being LGPLed, and PySide available, I suggest you use Qt. That e.g. allows you to use the super powerful QML technology for fast & good looking UIs written in a declarative, reactive way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. wxPython is a great cross-platform toolkit. It uses the actual widgets of the OS whenever possible. All the other toolkits draw their own widgets to look native. wxPython does not do mobile, however.

Comment: I don't really mind to switch frameworks (it is easier to do it now than after I get used to it), but now I'm curious about the reason behind this behavior because I don't see anyone else complaining about the same issue which means that this is either a non-issue (and perhaps I'm doing something wrong) or this is due an unfortunate combination of OSX/wxPython/Python version combination (I'm using Yosemite by the way).

Comment: @MikeDriscoll We might be of different opinion here, but that's exactly what makes it *not* great: it's a very leaky abstraction over the native toolkits. This actual question is an illustration of the problem: the API suggests there is a way to influence button-size, where the actual toolkit doesn't allow for that. wx is derived from windows, so it's a sensible choice for Python-UI-development on that platform. For all others, and especially a cross-platform-app, Qt is the much superior choice. Also, API-wise.

Comment: It depends on which is more important to you.  A not quite native LnF with a consistent API and behavior across platforms, or a truely native LnF using native widgets with the majority of the bumps and gaps of platform differences smoothed over.  Different people or projects will have different priorities here.  What may be "not great" to you may be "perfeclty awesome" to others.

Comment: Use "\nOK\n" for label instead of "OK" then probably the button will be expanded vertically to fit the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limit imposed by OSX.  The way the native button widget is drawn only allows it to be stretched horizontally, and the vertical size is fixed.  Or rather, as you've discovered, the widget itself can be larger than normal vertically, but it will only draw itself at a fixed height within that space.  It seems less neccessary with modern versions of OSX, but if you look at buttons in OSX from a few years ago you can probably see why this is so.  The esthetic graphical effect of the "tic-tack" or "capsule" buttons would be totally ruined if they were a non-standard vertical size, causing the images used to draw the buttons to be stretched.  wxWidgets follows the native plaform look and feel standards where possible, in this case it happens that Apple's standard is imposed upon us and wx can't offer the same level of flexibility that it usually does.

You do have some options however if you really want taller than normal buttons.  The native widgets have a few different standard sizes, which you can select using the `SetWindowVariant` method, although I don't think the variants would get as tall as you want.  Or you could use a generic button widget instead of a native one, such as `wx.lib.buttons.ThemedGenButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem in my little Software EventSoundControl.
Just a workaround: Use a multiline label and sizes of wxButton will work as desired!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button to stretch when you resize the frame, then you cannot use static sizes and positioning. You will need to put your widgets in a sizer. Then the sizer will manage the position / size of the widget(s) as you change the size of the frame. There are many examples on the [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/) that demonstrate how to use sizers. You might also find the following tutorial helpful:

- http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/

Comment: I know that @Mike, but that's not my issue at the moment (I deal with that later).  What I want is to define a custom starting size for the Button which is not working. Doing it for other widgets does work as you can see here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dq8571rvslwdm56/Screenshot%202015-03-16%2021.53.08.png

Comment: I wonder if the widget is overriding your size because it thinks the label won't fit. Try using some other sizes and see if they work. I've never had problems specifying a size before, so this is a bit weird

Comment: @RobinDunn pointed out the reason why this happens. TL;DR: I can either extend a Generic Button  or just try another framework (I ended up trying pyQt and it was worth it)